Is there a way to change BigQuery's Data Transfer wait / idle time between Run Dates?
I am using BigQuery Data Transfer to transfer my Google Ads data to BQ, I see that it's recommended that I use the Refresh Window parameter, as google may update historical records, I have it set to fetch the previous 3 days worth of data.. Each Run Date takes around 3-4 minutes, however Data Transfer automatically waits for around 30 minutes between each Run Date and the other. Is there a way to reduce this wait time, or remove it.. as this brings my total job time from excepted 9 - 12 minutes to 1+ hours.

I haven't found any task configuration parameters to change or disable this wait time!
